# SideMenu not appearing Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I can't seem to make the side menu work. What happens is the that I can see the sidebar button, but the page content disappears and the button doesn't click to open anything.

here is my route.js

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

      .state('jobStore', {
    url: '/homePage',
       views:{
      'userSettings':{
        templateUrl:"templates/userSettings.html",
        contoller: 'sideMenuCtrl'
      }
    }

    })
```

here is my side menu, called userSettings.html

```
<ion-side-menus>

  <ion-pane ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-chevron-left"></i> Back</ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-pane>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Left</h1>
        </header>
        <ion-content class="has-header">
<ion-list>
<ion-item id="userSettings-list-item11" class="  ">Application</ion-item>
                <ion-item id="userSettings-list-item12" class="  ">Dashboard</ion-item>
       </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

and my index.html

```
  <div>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">

        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
          <button menu-toggle="left"class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>

          <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-back">Back</ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </div>
```

Comment: route.js has a `contoller` typo.

Comment: That still didn't work :/

Comment: can you create plunker or codepen?

Comment: Please add `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/homePage')`